# how it I parse each row of data from the google sheets api with ansible's with_items?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets V4 Values collection and I am having trouble figuring out how to get each row to parse in to an {{ item }}

My Ansible ymal looks like.

```
tasks:
- name: debug url
  debug:
    msg: "{{ g_url }}"
- name: GET data from google spead sheet api
  uri:
    url: "{{ g_url }}"
    return_content: yes
    dest: /tmp/o_gd_form.json
  register: google_data
- name: whats the dump?
  debug:
    var: "{{ item.0 |to_json }}"
  with_items: "{{ google_data.json.values() }}" # this is the line that needs to be fixed
```

And the the responding json looks like:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
    ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
    ["Totals", "$135.5", "7", "3/20/2016"]
  ],
}
```

I can't seem figure out how to write the the `with_items` to return an `{{ item }}` of json like `["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"]`.

any help or do I need to split this task out to some middleware parser?

The Google sheets api documentation is at:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/reading

Comment: What is your expected output (full, not what it's "like..."). "Of" can be used as possessive as well as "of the type", it's unclear which one you meant. Besides you have syntax error in `debug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want, use:

```
    - debug: msg="Name={{ item.0 }} Cost={{ item.1 }}"
      with_list: "{{ google_data.json['values'] }}"
```

There are two problems in your code:

1. `values` is a special keyword, so you can't access `json.values`, but should use `json['values']` instead.
2. `with_items` flattens the list of lists, so you end up with long list of strings. You should use `with_list` to iterate over outer list (rows) and get inner lists (column values) as items.