# Ansible: Access private Google Sheets

Tags: linux, google-sheets, ansible, ansible-2.x

In our organization, we have all sheets as private. is there a way to provide auth credentials and access the sheet using ansible? I need to use the data from the sheet and iterate over a task
Google Sheets has the below data. I need to get Username, Email, and Firstname and iterate through a task

[image]

I used the below task from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283238/how-it-i-parse-each-row-of-data-from-the-google-sheets-api-with-ansibles-with-i) but it didn't help as the
sheet is private

```
- name: GET data from google spreadsheet api
  uri:
    url: "{{ google_url }}"
    return_content: yes
    dest: /tmp/userinfo.csv
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but "Is there a way to access private Google Sheets" sounds like "Is there a way to hack into people's private sheets and data." And that is illegal. Please clarify your intention.

Comment: Assuming that you're not trying to hack anyone, but trying to access information you're legally entitled to ... I'm afraid you're on your own, the `uri` module doesn't provide `oauth2` facilities at this point in time, to get access to data in google sheets that aren't public you'll need to implement a module yourself or use the shell/command modules in clever ways with other tools.

Comment: @Erik Tyler. No, I am not hacking into ppl private sheets. So in our organization, we have all sheets as private. is there a way to provide auth credentials and access the sheet using ansible? I need to use the data from the sheet and iterate over a task

Comment: Access to google apis requires an oauth exchange, rather than basic http authentication. This isn't available with the `uri` module. You could probably write your own module to do this (there are certainly examples out there of using Python to access information in Google Sheets, including the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)).

Answer (score 1):

As google APIs require oauth tokens, you will not be able to easily retrieve that private data with ansible. In theory is possible to pass required headers  with those secrets but I am afraid that you may find it more problematic to fully integrate the process.

Instead of starting with Ansible, try making it work with `curl`. Once you made it work with curl, making it work with Ansible will be very easy.